# docker-compose config changes external: false to external: true

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### Question

In my `docker-compose.yml` I have `external: false` but `docker-compose config` gives me `external: true`.

What is the reason for this change of value? My assumption was that this command just validates the file and performs only cosmetic changes.

### How to reproduce

```
$> cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3.4'

volumes:
      test-volume:
          name: test-name
          external: false

services:
    test-service:
        image: test-image
```

---

```
$> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml config
services:
  test-service:
    image: test-image
version: '3.4'
volumes:
  test-volume:
    external: true
    name: test-name
```

---

```
$> docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471
```

### Update:

@Nicola proved that this is a bug: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I verified this behaviour and what you described, in my opinion, deserves an issue in https://github.com/docker/compose/issues